# Will redirecting my domain name temporarily to a placeholder website affect my SEO?

Tags: seo, redirects, registration

So we have this new customer, and they wanted to register their domain name themselves.

Now they have this old company and old website which is outdated. So what they did, is register their domain names and redirected it to their old website.

Normally I advice to not do this, just register and keep it, until the new site is up but it's already been done.

So I have this question, should I act immediately telling them to disable the redirect, or should I just leave it.

I know the old website is going to be indexed, this is not a good thing but my question is how harmful this is?

Comment: Is the old company/website completely unrelated to the new one?

Comment: no not completely, but it's pitching on high profile customers, the old site was pitching on everybody. We don't want to link both companies but it should be no problem to list them both in search results.

Comment: What is the point in buying a new domain and redirecting it to the old domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it truly is a redirect of a new domain (and I say this because a lot of companies get this wrong) then there will only be the root domain indexed in search engines anyhow so when the new website goes live and the redirect removed, it won't take a search engine long to see that and then start indexing the new site on the new domain.

There is minimal concerns from a performance perspective. Only a case of whether the customer is happy for visitors to see their old website (but its live anyway at another domain any traffic passing through the new domain will probably be zero anyway - if Google even decide to index it).

Nothing to worry about. Either/or.

Comment: It is a proper 301 redirect, guess I'll let it be for the meanwhile  thanks guys